# Display Instagram Account Photos on website with new Instagram Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

So with the new Instagram Graph API, I'm super confused on how it works and what permissions need to be granted to make this work.

**Here is what I'm trying to achieve**:
Display media from my own Instagram account that I have access too on our corporate website - I can't use the Instagram API since it's getting deprecated.

**What I've done so far**:
Have a Facebook Page linked with a Instagram Account
Have a Business Manager account

**Questions that I have**:
Do I need a 'Login via Facebook/Instagram' button on my website to display my own account media?

Which 'permission' do I need to be able to grab the media from my own account? Instagram_basic, etc..?

Does anyone have a good guide that describes these features - I don't need auto posters, or anything else, I just want to be able to display the pictures of my Instagram account on our website.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you reviewed their [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/) guide?  It seems to go over things pretty well.

Comment: I've checked it out but it doesn't state whether you need to integrate 'Login via Facebook' to show the media of an account.

Comment: The second section is explicitly titled "Implement Facebook Login"

Comment: @Sema I have the same question, were you able to find an answer?

Comment: @MieElMansy, yes I got it all figured out and I'm pulling in my media with cURL using PHP.

Comment: @Sema can you please share the code snippet?